Finding a Linear Algebra reading topic
I'm looking for a linear algebra topic to assign to a group of undergraduate engineering students who are not majoring in mathematics. The assignment should meet the following criteria:

The topic should involve a real-life application of linear algebra.
It should be challenging enough to occupy the students for about a month. During this time, they will study the topic through provided documents. The students have a background in Calculus (single and multivariable) and numerical analysis (of course Linear Algebra as well).
The focus should be on understanding the mathematical analysis behind the application.

I'm struggling to find a suitable topic for a few reasons:

Many standard topics, such as applications in circuit analysis, input-output models, or simple Markov models, have already been covered in class or are easily found in standard textbooks.
On the other hand, more advanced topics, like the Harris corner detection algorithm, seem to lack accessible and comprehensive resources for students. Most textbooks I’ve found only briefly introduce the idea without going into depth.

I’m hoping for suggestions on a topic that provide the right balance and come with good reference materials. Any recommendations would be greatly appreciated.

For such things, you can try COMAP ...  https://www.comap.com/

@StevenGubkin Students may come from diverse backgrounds, including chemistry, electrical engineering, and computer science.

@GeraldEdgar It seems there aren't many free resources available.

Maybe Resources for Teaching Linear Algebra edited by David Carlson & Charles R. Johnson & David C. Lay & A. Duane Porter & Ann E. Watkins & William Watkins (1997), especially Part V: Applications of Linear Algebra on pp. 223-287. Also Linear Algebra Gems.

Wht about the Google matrix ? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_matrix

For computer science students, an obvious choice might be applications of linear algebra to graph theory. Also, this is a cool use of matrices: Using the quick raise of matrices to power to write a very fast interpreter of a simple programming language

Perhaps refinery operations and its "linear programming model" (which is a famous term used in the industry, for getting the most $$ out of the darned thing).
I understand the refinery itself, but not linear algebra.  So, I can't give a good perspective on the reference materials.  But there's a lot out there.
And then the area itself is a pretty core one in the economy, with lots of jobs associated and such. And there's lots of heavy metal and heat transfer and fluid flow.  So, I think it will appeal to most engineers (but especially chemical and mechanical).
P.s.  A very good reference manual on the refinery system itself is here:
https://www.amazon.com/Petroleum-Refining-Nontechnical-Language-William-dp-1593702809/dp/1593702809/
Very easy read and fast slide up the steep edge of the knowledge curve.  I read it the weekend before starting a job at a refinery.  Gives the names of the major pots and kettles and how they work together.  It's not linear algebra per se, but shows the major tradeoffs involved, and has little (high school) algebra problems.

You could try Application-Inspired Linear Algebra by Moon, Asaki & Snipes. It's set up around going into reasonable depth, albeit in a gentle introductory way, in two application areas: radiography/tomography and heat diffusion. Both could be interesting and motivating to engineering students.
From the preface:

We wrote this book with the aim of inspiring the reader to explore mathematics. Our goal is to provide opportunities for students to discover mathematical ideas in the context of applications. Before any formal mathematics,
the text starts with two main data applications—radiography/tomography of
images and heat diffusion—to inspire the creation and development of Linear
Algebra concepts.
The applications are presented primarily through a sequence of explorations. Readers first learn about one aspect of a data application, and then, in
an inquiry framework, they develop the mathematics necessary to investigate
the application. After each exploration, the reader will see the standard
definitions and theorems for a first-year Linear Algebra course, but with the
added context of the applications.

In the case of radiography/tomography, students are introduced to the basic ideas not only of linear algebra but the field of inverse problems. In heat diffusion, students see how linear algebra arises in solving a discretized partial differential equation. With your students' background in multivariable calculus and numerical analysis, this should be doable.

The analysis of states of self-stress in mechanisms and structures in mechanical engineering provides a good application of basic linear algebra in which the rank and defect of a certain matrix have interpretations related with degree of mobility and range of motion. There are several articles by Sergio Pellegrino (e.g. Analysis of prestressed mechanisms) but this stuff and other similar applications of linear algebra can also be found in textbooks on design of mechanisms and linkages (see, for example, the book Forms and concepts for lightweight structures by Miura and Pellegrino). What I mention specifically is called the Maxwell rules by engineers because it goes back (without much modification except for modernization of language) to Maxwell's article On the calculation of the equilibrium and stiffness of frames.
While these sorts of things are straightforward applications of linear algebra this is sometimes lost in engineering accounts that resist using modern linear algebra terminology and notation.
